# file in .exe not running properly but in visual studio code is working fine

Tags: python

i am looking for a solution on how i make my .exe python file works well just like in visual studio code. After converting the python file into .exe, it wont run well as it shows traceback error. [Traceback Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9g1iN.png) ..
[Reconvert again with --onefile -w in cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ci5mQ.png)

Code:

```py
from time import sleep
from newspaper import Article, Config
    import nltk
from newspaper.article import ArticleException, ArticleDownloadState

def get_News():
    while True: 
        print ("Enter URL: ")
        url = input('')
        print("\n")
        user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0'

        config = Config()
        config.browser_user_agent = user_agent
        config.request_timeout = 10

        article = Article(url, config=config, lang='en')
        slept = 0
        article.download()
        article.parse()    

        title = article.title
        author = article.authors
        pub_date = article.publish_date
        text = article.text 

        article.nlp()

        print('Display Title, Author and Publish Date:')
        print(title ,author, pub_date)
        print ('\n' +'Display Text from Article: ' + '\n' + text)
        print ('\n' + 'Display Article Summary: ')
        print(article.summary)
        print('\n')
        print('Display Keywords: ')
        print(article.keywords)

        if url == '':
            print('No URL Found. Exiting the Program...')
            break
        if __name__ == '__main__': 
        get_News()
```

I am using Visual Studio Code and to convert into .exe, i use py -m PyInstaller --onefile -.py

Thanks for your help and solutions !

Comment: can you `print(article)` before `article.nlp()` to see if it's parsed? does it work correctly outside visualstudio, as a .py file?

Comment: hi, i have tried print(article) before the article.nlp() and yes, there are text ( title, text, summary, and keywords)

Comment: try directly running the .py file without vs code, see if the problem still exists? is it possible that you are converting the wrong/old file to .exe?

Comment: Hello, i have tried running directly on the .py file and it is working perfectly fine as well as the output. i doubt that i convert the wrong file since i use my file directory during the convertion on cmd ( cd C:\\.........).

Answer (score 0):

Please use command `PyInstaller --onefile <filename>` instead of yours. You are not writing a program with only UI, and `-w` means not using command window, which refer to `stdin`, `stdout`, `stderr` is invalid. And that means `input()`, `print()`, etc. is not available.

Comment: Oh i see, after trying the command PyInstaller --onefile <filename> i am able to have the user input but still there is a traceback error which is similar to my image [1]

Comment: Maybe you can try again in a new python version with only package in need in this file. I have tried on my computer and it ran well. (However, I don't know how to input correct link for test.) You can try to use anaconda to get a "clean" version of python.

Answer (score -1):

Somehow i managed to solve it, seems like the newspaper\article.py is not inside the file directory of my exe program. So i copy paste the newspaper folder from Python and paste it inside the file of my exe program and it finally worked.